# HttpWebRequest receives "WebException: The request timed out"

Tags: c#, php, ssl, unity-game-engine, httpwebrequest

After endless research and testing of different combinations, I'm clueless right now.

I receive an `WebException: The request timed out` only if I my `byteArray` gets filled by something else than `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("")`. (Like "hello")

The server setup is a https-request to a Google Load Balancer, which communicates with the backend via HTTP. The backend is an Apache with PHP.

For testing purposes (self-signed SSL-Cert) I have this:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
        delegate (object s,  
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,  
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, 
            System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors){ 
        return true; 
    };
```

- If I enter the URL in my web-browser (Chrome), I get a response.
- If I use the HTTP-requester from Mozilla with or without content to send, I get the correct response data (after adding an SSL-Security exception)
- If I run my code below with `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("")` everything works (except I cannot send data and therefore receive what I want)

Here's the code I'm using.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://someurl.com/some.php");
webRequest.Proxy = null;
webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.Timeout = 3000;

byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("someData");  //works if empty
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

Stream postData = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
postData.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
postData.Close();

HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse(); //ERROR MESSAGE
Stream dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string data = reader.ReadToEnd(); //output data

reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
webResponse.Close ();
```

The exact error (btw, all this happens in the Unity3D editor):

`WebException: The request timed out
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse ()`

So why on earth is it not working, once there is something the GetRequestStream has to write?

Thanks and all the best,
Kruegbert

---

**..::Addendum**

- if I increase the timeout, it just takes longer until the same msg appears.
- If I write `webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length+1` I receive a response, but it's a WebException error: `ProtocolError`
- If I write `webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length-1` I get the `ProtocolViolationException`
- I already tried the same with try/catch/using resulting in the same behaviour

Comment: Just to be sure, hopefully you tried `webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length`.

Comment: Yeah I did. Afterwards I was just experimenting with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out, why it was not working - still I don't know why it behaves like this. (Maybe a UnityEditor thing)

I added

```
webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
```

and everything worked. No more timeout errors. And yes `webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;` results in the timeout error.

However, making a HttpRequest from the web succeeds with either of these: `HTTP/1.1`, `HTTP/1.0 (with Host header)`, `HTTP/1.0 (without Host header)`

Comment: Just to update my answer working with
`webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;`
I have to add
`webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;`since the server does not support HTTP/1.1 100 Continue response.

Comment: This fix also works for me. However, I'd really like to know *why*?

Some more info: I'm also working in Unity, but this happens to me on iPhone, not in the editor, and only after the app has been running for a while. The backend is Amazon CloudFront.